# Por qué no funciona mi condición?

Tags: c#, condiciones, consola

Continúo desarrollando el programa en consola en el cual se simula un ascensor. El edificio tiene únicamente 30 pisos y por el momento estoy tratando de crear una condición para que una vez el usuario suba o baje a X piso, se le vuelva a preguntar que si quiere acceder a otro piso, pero simplemente no funciona.

Aquí lo que llevo de momento:

```
string userInput;
short floorNumber;
bool wantsToContinue;
bool isInvalid = true;

Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido! El edificio cuenta con un total de 30 pisos. \nPara subir  digite la letra S, para bajar digite la letra B");
Console.Write("Seleccione una opción ==> ");


do
{
    userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if (userInput != "S" && userInput != "B")
        Console.Write("Opción inválida, intente de nuevo ==> ");
    else
        break;
} while (true);
do
{
    if (userInput == "S") {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("A continuación indique el piso al que desea subir ==> ");
        floorNumber = Convert.ToInt16(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        while (floorNumber < 30 && floorNumber > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Subiendo...");
            Console.WriteLine($"Ahora te encuentras en el piso {floorNumber}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    if (userInput == "B")
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("A continuación indique el piso al que desea bajar ==> ");
        floorNumber = Convert.ToInt16(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        while (floorNumber < 30 && floorNumber > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bajando...");
            Console.WriteLine($"Ahora te encuentras en el piso {floorNumber}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Desea acceder a otro piso? (s/n) ==> ");
    userInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
    if (userInput == "n")
    {
        wantsToContinue = false;
    }
    else if (userInput == "s")
    {
        wantsToContinue = true;
    }
    else
    {
        wantsToContinue = true;
        while (isInvalid)
        {
            Console.Write("\nOpción inválida intente de nuevo: ");
            userInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
            if (userInput == "n" || userInput == "s")
            {
                isInvalid = false;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.Clear();
} while (wantsToContinue) ;
```

Como pueden observar la función se encuentra implementada pero no logro hacer que cumpla con su cometido que es el de una vez el usuario haya llegado al piso al que deseaba ir le pregunte si quiere acceder a otro piso o no sino que una vez muestra el mensaje indicándole al usuario el piso en el que se encuentra se repite una y otra vez cada que se le da a una tecla sin mostrar el siguiente mensaje que sería el de

```
Console.Write("Desea acceder a otro piso? (s/n) ==> ");
```

He estado pensando por mucho rato pero sinceramente no encontré la solución y por eso me dirijo a ustedes.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No te falta un corchete? En el segundo `do` terminas el corchete del while pero no lo comienzas (Y la tabulación no es muy buena...) Son dos partes de código o algo?

Comment: No entiendo, todos los corchetes están porque el ide no muestra ningún error

Comment: Siempre puedes mirarlo en [Revisiones de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/305950/revisions) que puedes acceder en el botón de `editada hace x min`. También he solucionado la tabulación para que sea más legible

Comment: Listo, ya la he aprobado.Gracias.

Comment: El problema considero que está en `userInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();`. Posiblemente para solucionarlo necesites hacer `Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString()` [Ejemplo Doc Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.8) Ya que no le has puesto un `ReadKey(true)` que devuelve la tecla (En la misma documentación más abajo está)

Comment: Pues.. no, no va :C

Comment: Prueba si funciona con `Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();` ya que lo has puesto antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que no observo en el codigo es donde incrementas o decrementas la variable `floorNumber` para que refleje la llegada a ese piso, o quizas no es un `while` el que tengas que usar sino un `if`

creo que podrias simplificar mucho el codigo quitando lo repetido, algo como esto

```
Console.Clear();

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido! El edificio cuenta con un total de 30 pisos. \nPara subir  digite la letra S, para bajar digite la letra B");
    Console.Write("Seleccione una opción ==> ");

    string userInput;
    do
    {
        userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        if (userInput == "S" || userInput == "B")
            break;

        Console.Write("Opción inválida, intente de nuevo ==> ");

    } while (true);


    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("A continuación indique el piso al que desea {0} ==> ", userInput == "S" ? "subir" : "bajar");
    short floorNumber = Convert.ToInt16(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

    if (floorNumber < 30 && floorNumber > 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(userInput == "S" ? "Subiendo..." : "Bajando...");
        Console.WriteLine($"Ahora te encuentras en el piso {floorNumber}");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

    char otropiso;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Desea acceder a otro piso? (s/n) ==> ");
        char otropiso = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        if (otropiso == 'n' || otropiso == 's')
            break;

        Console.Write("\nOpción inválida intente de nuevo: ");

    }while(true);

    if (otropiso == 'n')
        break;

    Console.Clear();

}while(true);
```

veras que se puede usar el `break` o el `continue` segun quieras volver al principio del `do..while`

Ademas cambie el `while` que valida a que piso quieres ir por un `if`, si querias reflejar como se mueve por los pisos deberias sumar o restar una variable desde el piso actual al desptino, pero para eso deberas conservar cual es el piso en que se encuentra y asi reflejar el movimiento

Tambien use `if en linea` para poder reusar codigo segun sube o baja cambiar los textos

[?: operator (C# reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: Ya lo he probado y va bien,pero se da el caso de que si por ejemplo, elijo subir al piso 22 y cuando salga el mensaje de si quiero acceder a otro piso únicamente me deja seguir subiendo más no bajar, ya que la sentencia que se repite es la misma que se eligió al principio

Comment: entonces la pregunta de subir o bajar tambien hay que integrarla en un while global

Comment: edite el codigo, valida si asi pregunta si se quiere seguir subiendo o bajando

Comment: Ya ha funcionado, agregué también una variable para que almacene el piso en el que el usuario se había quedado. Ha ido de maravilla. Muchísimas gracias Leandro.

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar si dos objetos del tipo string son iguales, utiliza la función Equals().

Ejemplo:

```
string a1,a2;
a1 = "A";
a2 = "A";

if (a1.Equals(a2)){
  Console.WriteLine("Iguales!");
}
else{
  Console.WriteLine("Distintos!");
}
```